# Didn't Receive a call after I completed a mission in GTA 5, no more main missions

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

After completing the mission "Minisub" with Trevor I was supposed to receive a call from Wade telling me the Heist was ready. I did not receive the call and finished a ton of Strangers & Freaks.

Answer (score 1):

A number of things to solve this:

1. make a new save and delete the old save
2. try phoning people as all three protagonists
3. try sleeping a few times after each other
4. Try fast traveling in a taxi.

If this doesn't help, you should probably reinstall the game or try again from an older save point